# Magento Multiple Grid Ajax Issue

Tags: magento-1.7

I am creating module which using ajax to load the order's product in to the grid , while user enter the order # in text box and press enter the Aajx fetches that particular product's order and loads it in to the grid.

Now the above process is working fine First time.But when i enter another order # in another text box the ajax calls again and reload the product data in second grid , but it overrides second grid data with first grid , and finally both grid data remains same , i have debugged everything from ajax call, to query etc..

i have changed the Grid.php file and edited the `$this->setId('OrderProductsGrid'.$order_id);` dynamic but no luck yet.

Please advice what i am missing here..

Comment: In theory this should work. Are you sure `$order_id` is not empy when setting the grid id?

Comment: Sounds like same CSS id/classes, so the content is written in two instead of one grid.